# A viewmodel without a view, can it be justified?

Tags: oop, mvvm

In an MVVM application, is it be frowned upon to have a viewmodel without a view?

My justification for having such a viewmodel is that the underlying model fires some events caught by the viewmodel which then in turn notifies other viewmodels of this event using an event aggregator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM, `ViewModels` must be independant of `Views`. So, **YES**, a `Viewmodel` can be without a `View`.